# Urgent question - failed plugin and now getting internal server error

Tags: plugins

Hope someone can help asap - we tried to install a plugin through craftcms 3 (Cache Flag) and now getting 'The configuration for the "gc" component must contain a "class" element.'

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems unrelated to the Cache Flag plugin, and more likely due to some bad code in `config/app.php` (or `app.web.php`).

If you have either of those files, check what changes you’ve made to it/them recently.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've replaced that and now get 'Setting unknown property: craft\models\Info::config'. We did have a GC setting in there by setting garbage collection timeout.

Comment: Did you somehow end up downgrading Craft to < 3.1?

Comment: I was on 3.1.23 I believe beforehand. Just ran install on cache flag, then go the internal server error. I ran composer to uninstall cache-flag and then ran composer update.

Comment: I've managed to get it live, however, no plugins are showing and I can't upgrade / install any as I believe all the versions messed up whilst I ran composer update after removing the cache flag module. Do you know a work around this? Thanks again for the assistance, much appreciated.

Comment: Down to one error. When running composer update, it fails with 'Setting unknown property: craft\redactor\Field::removeInlineStyles'. :(